# Confusion regarding ApplicationContext in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

I was referring to Spring configuration related blogs and came across some information on applicationContext. One article it is mentioned:

> "In most simple cases, the ApplicationContext(defaule name for file is applicationContext.xml) is unnecessary. It is generally used to contain beans that are shared between all servlets in a webapp. If you only have one servlet, then there's not really much point, unless you have a specific use for it."

Where it is also mentioned:

> "If you are not explicitly declaring the context configuration file name in web.xml using the contextConfigLocation param, Spring will search for the applicationContext.xml under WEB-INF folder and throw FileNotFoundException if it could not find this file."

Above two statements seems to be contradicting (though it is not). Can you please help clarifying above or suggests me link that clarifies above points?

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify with the blog's author? Hard to explain author's thoughts without even seeing the whole context (and a little bit of googling indicates that this doesn't come from a single established and reputable blog, but from a series of content-scrapers and re-publishers, probably compounding confusion due to the Chinese whispers effect). The official documentation and tutorials should be your first place to look when in doubt.

Answer (score 0):

From : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_applicationcontext_container.htm

> The Application Context is spring's more advanced container.
>       Similar to BeanFactory it can load bean definitions, wire beans     together and dispense beans upon request.
>     Additionally it adds more enterprise-specific functionality such as the ability to resolve textual messages from a properties file and the ability to publish application events to interested event listeners. This container is defined by the org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext interface.

That means Application Context is a container and it can load beans from xml files and from  @Bean annotations from your java code. With recent spring versions you can configure all of your beans in java code and not use xml files.